# what does this log mean Information: Normalizing '_blazor'?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

When I open the `DevTool` in development mode I see always this message:

```
[2022-02-15T15:08:47.539Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 
'https://localhost:5001/_blazor'
[2022-02-15T15:08:47.590Z] Information: WebSocket connected to 
wss://localhost:5001/_blazor?id=XXXXX
```

When I open also `DevTool` in staging mode I see only this message:

```
[2022-02-15T15:08:47.539Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 
'https://localhost:5001/_blazor'
```

I don't understand What does this message mean and how can I hide them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Normalization` is referring to [URI normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_normalization), which is to make a standardized form of a URI, or in this case standardizing the URL.

In a blazor server app, the default endpoint for the SignalR connection is `_blazor`, and this is being normalized to the absolute URL `https://localhost:5001/_blazor` in your case.

To configure SignalR client logging, [see this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-signalr-client-logging-blazor-server). You probably want to configure your logging level to `None`:

...

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false"></script>
<script>
  Blazor.start({
    configureSignalR: function (builder) {
      builder.configureLogging("none");
    }
  });
</script>
```

Also see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=dotnet#configure-client-options) for the different logging configurations.